# Concatenate selected values from dynamic dropdowns using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

Question:

How do I get the value from each dropdown and concatenate them to create a string of characters from those values?  These dropdowns are dynamically generated so I cannot select them by ID etc.

Details:

I have a list on n number of dropdowns depending on the product selected.
Each dropdown is related to a character in a partnumber thus whichever is selected builds a string of characters to a variable to create a part number i.e.  "B119"
Edit (include code):

```
    <dt>
    <dd>
        <select class="ddlmain" name="product_attribute_180_3_17" id="product_attribute_180_3_17">
            <option value="0">---</option>
            <option value="B">Blue</option>
            <option value="G">Green</option>
            <option value="R">Red</option>
        </select>
    </dd>
</dt>
<dt>
    <dd>
        <select class="ddlmain" name="product_attribute_180_1_18" id="product_attribute_180_1_18">
            <option value="0">---</option>
            <option value="119">Left</option>
            <option value="120">Right</option>
            <option value="121">Center</option>
        </select>
    </dd>
</dt>
```

Comment: If you post the resulting HTML markup of your dropdowns with some context in which order you want the values to be concatenated it will be easier to make a jQuery selector which will be useful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you can give the group of dropdowns a specific class name.
2. use the classname as selector. iterate them and get it's value. concat the value to a variable.

in my mind, your html would be like this :

```
<select class="dropdownCode code_1" id="code_1">
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">tiga</option>
</select>    

<select class="dropdownCode code_2" id="code_2">
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="alpha">alpha</option>
    <option value="omega">omega</option>    
</select>    

<select class="dropdownCode code_3" id="code_3">
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="X">X</option>
    <option value="Y">Y</option>
    <option value="Z">Z</option>
</select>    

<button class="create">Create</button>
```

and the jquery is like this :

```
var returnVal = '';
$('.create').click(function() {
   $('.dropdownCode').each(function() {
       returnVal += $(this).val();
   });                    
   alert(returnVal);
});
```

Comment: If you have the javascript/jquery syntax structure because I am still learning...thank you

Comment: ah i see you already post your html...so it's similar i think.. you can use the ddlmain as selector. but btw on what event do you wish the jquery populate the string code? my example is on click of 1 button

Comment: Thanks!!  I did have to scope the returnVal =''; to prevent concatenating on each click but other than that it worked!